# how we fetch image in Angular 16 using backend get API in Laravel

Tags: html, css, angular, laravel

```
import { Component, EnvironmentInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { OrdersDataService } from '../services/orders-data.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'; 

@Component({   selector: 'app-formimage',   templateUrl: './formimage.component.html',   styleUrls: \['./formimage.component.css'\] }) export class FormimageComponent {   showtest:any;   imageurl:any;  

constructor(private ordersData: OrdersDataService) 
{       
this.ordersData.showtest().subscribe((data)=\>{         this.showtest=data;       }); } /// Function to decode the image filename before using it in the \<img\> tag 

decodeImageFileName(imageFileName: string): string {   const decodedName = decodeURIComponent(imageFileName);   re\`your text\`turn decodedName; }   } 

\<table\>     
\<thead\>       
\<tr\>         
\<th\>product Id\</th\>         
\<th\>product name\</th\>         
\<th\>product category\</th\>         
\<th\>product quantity\</th\>         
\<th\>product price\</th\>         
\<th\>product description\</th\>         
\<th\>image\</th\>       
\</tr\>     
\</thead\>     
\<tbody\>       
\<tr \*ngFor="let item of showtest"\>         
\<td\>{{item.id}}\</td\>         
\<td\>{{item.product_name}}\</td\>         
\<td\>{{item.category}}\</td\>         
\<td\>{{item.quantity}}\</td\>         
\<td\>{{item.price}}\</td\>         
\<td\>{{item.description}}\</td\>         
\<td\>\<img style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" \[src\]="'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/product_images/' + decodeImageFileName(item.image)"\>\</td\>               
\</tr\>     
\</tbody\>   
\</table\>      

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class OrdersDataService 
{    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { } 

showtest(){
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products'); } 
}
```

So, this is my Angular code. In this code when I want to fetch data in front-end using backend Laravel get API, all data prints in frontend except image, for image it shows a can't GET error in console 404 error, and also, when I want to fetch image from backend it can add some invalid character in image, so image name is change, but backend API works properly, I tested and also save same name image save into database, that name I uploaded, but front-end it can't work, or image in Laravel backend save into storage/app/public/product_image path.
So can anyone help me solve this issue?